# Chain across the matrix

Tags: recursion, matrix

Given a binary matrix, we want to check if there exists a path across nodes on two ends, such as:

0 1 0 0 0

0 1 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 0

0 0 0 1 0

this case has a chain of one's from the first to the last row which is stretched over in some of the rows. Similarly, the result should be true even if there's a chain from left to the right column.

I thought about writing a recursively exploring function for each positive element through-out the top row and the left column. Could you suggest something better?

Answer (score 0):

one of solutions would be to use `Set`:

1. Go through each row
2. If field value is `1` and one of its already visited neighbours is inside the `Set`, add its coordinates `(x,y)` to the `Set`
3. At the end, check if `Set` contains any coordinates from the last row - if so, there is a path.

as you didn't mention which language you would like to use, here's how it looks like in Javascript (ES6):

```
let matrix = '01000
01100
00110
00010'.split('\n').map((row) => { return row.split('') });

let set = new Set();
let cols = matrix[0].length;
let rows = matrix.length;

for(let col=0; col < cols; col++){
    if(matrix[0][col] == '1'){
        set.add(`0,{col}`);
    }
}

for(let row=1; row < rows-1; row++){
    for(let col=1; col < cols; col++){
        if(matrix[row][col] == '1' && 
          (set.has(`{row-1},{col-1}`) || 
           set.has(`{row-1},{col}`) || 
           set.has(`{row-1},{col+1}`) || 
           set.has(`{row},{col-1}`))){
            set.add(`{row},{col}`);
        }
    }
}

let row = rows-1;

for(let col=0; col < cols; col++){
    if(matrix[row][col] == '1' && 
      (set.has(`{row-1},{col-1}`) || 
       set.has(`{row-1},{col}`) || 
       set.has(`{row-1},{col+1}`) || 
       set.has(`{row},{col-1}`))){
        // HAS PATH
    }
}
```